# React Native WebView Invoke onMessage

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

```
<WebView
source={{ uri: url1 }}
style={{ flex: 1 }}
onMessage={this.onMessage}
/>
```

url1 will redirect to url2 after completing a payment. The question is how can invoke `onMessage` in url2? I tried `window.postMessage` in url2, but that did not invoke the Webview `onMessage` that is on the client-side. What am I missing here?

The html in my url2 is like following:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="event">Go Back</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('event').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.postMessage('string', '*')}, false);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: try document.postMessage  instead of window.postmessage

Comment: @RajatGupta ,is document one of the web API? I tried it, and it didn't invoke the onMessage.

Comment: No its no an web api document represents Dom ....containg HTML similar to
window object .

Comment: debug your code , you can only sent strings through postMessage. have you bind this.onMessage . Try to send message from app to web .

Comment: @RajatGupta My `onMessage` function is in arrow function.